# IOS link item in containerview to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I just started IOS development and I was trying to build a simple app where I place items (`views`) in a `container view` and show the right `container view` when needed. Whenever I try to create an outlet for my subviews in my `ViewController.swift`, Xcode does not let me do that.I have also tried writing the outlet code in my `ViewController.swift` and linking it back to the story board and failed.

Comment: sounds like your `ViewController` isn't hooked up to your view. I think its the identity inspector from memory (the icon on the left of the attribute inspector) but make sure that the viewcontroller's class is `ViewController` and not `UIVewController`

Comment: only the main viewController was hooked up. the subviews in the ContainerView weren't. thank you :)

Comment: Good luck with your app :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `class` property of your `View Controller` and subviews in the `Storyboard` under **Identity Inspector** (on the right side of your Xcode window) matches *exactly* the name of your classes, such as in the example below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: only the main viewController was hooked up RIGHT . the subviews in the ContainerView weren't. fixing those did the trick,  thank you :)